# Redeploy failed git deployment

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Occasionally, for whatever reason, when I deploy a commit via azure websites local git repo, it cannot find one of our remote repos (server down, whatever) and so it fails to retrieve certain nuget packages, causing the whole deployment to fail.

In this scenario, the only way I've found to force the deployment to execute again is to commit another change; this is no bueno. Is there a way to re-run a failed git deployment without triggering the auto deployment via a new commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto [Azure Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), Select the DEPLOYMENTS tab of your site.  Select the failed deployment item and you should see the retry button on the bottom command bar.  Try click it.   You can also force deploy any successful items by selecting it and click redeploy button.

Comment: When last I checked, failed deployments didn't have a retry button. Will check next time it happens.

Comment: What about when azure thinks it succeeded but it actually failed?

Comment: How would this be automated using a continuous integration server?